# Getting Pictures from folder directory in PHP

Tags: php

I have a folder directory set up like this in my htdocs:

claas2/TractorPics\5484474\Received\ => and then a bunch of images inside

im using php to put the picture from MySQL database where the file path is stored rather than all the pictures and so that they can be changed easily.

php:

```
if ( $_REQUEST['rec_pic'] ) {
    $order_id = $_POST['rec_pic'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `active` = '1' AND `order_id` = '$order_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $dir = $row['rec_pic'];
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<a href='#'><img src='".$file."' /></a>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            closedir($handle);
         }
     }
}
```

When i echo this out i get an error saying that that file directory does not exist but if i were to do src it in an image it works just fine. What am i doing wrong here?

the php file that get getting the request is in the directory

claas2\db\ajax

Comment: _“What am i doing wrong here?”_ – you are confusing file system paths with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty messy path you have:

```
claas2/TractorPics\5484474\Recieved\
```

Try:

```
claas2\TractorPics\5484474\Recieved\
```

or

```
claas2/TractorPics/5484474/Recieved/
```

but do not mix separators.

**EDIT**

You are mixing path with URL. And it works because you are using `\` as path segment separator, which your browser converts to `/` while sending request to webserver and your server is now Windows based I guess, therefore `\` is invalid as path separator for file system on server. Do

```
$path = str_replace('\\', `/`, $pathFromDb);
```

and use result instead of data from db as you use now.

Comment: that didn't get her done haha, im wondering if it could be that my php file that is doing all the work is not in the parent directory

Comment: You use relative paths, so pay attention to it as, especially with code in included files, it may sometimes be misleading, resulting is incorrect path. Build **full** path and check. If it is invalid, see how valid one looks like and check what you are doing wrong (or missing stuff like `../` etc).

Comment: <img src="TractorPics\5484474\Recieved\1118.jpg"> and worked fine and when i pull it from my database it is TractorPics\5484474\Recieved\ but it tells me that directory does not exist